# Building an electron app with for Windows now failing

Tags: electron, squirrel.windows

I had to upgrade my Electron packages in order to do DMG builds on OS X High Sierra.  Ever since then I can no longer do Squirrel builds for Windows.  I'm able to build for NSIS, but that appears to be 64-bit only and does not include the updater package.  I'm using Squirrel as we still have a lot of 32-bit clients and we supply auto updates via a Squirrel server.

It appears there's something incompatible between the old iconUrl parameter required by Squirrel and the new icon parameter.  I've updated all my packages and the squirrel builder is a comparable version to electron builder, yet still no luck.  Has anyone found a way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another round of updating all the related builder packages (and adding a new dependency that popped up), I had to move the iconUrl out of the build key and into a squirrelWindows key and remove NSIS completely.  All good with this new config!